# exim: how to configure delay between messages?

Tags: php, email, exim

I need to configure exim4 to wait for a ~1second delay between messages to a same host. Is this possible?

I need this basically because GMail sometimes complains saying that "im sending too many mails to them", and they believe its spam.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
sleep(1);//1 is a second
```

function of PHP to send it slowly.

Comment: I'm looking for an exim-level solution. Messages are sent in a loop just after clicking 'Send', so it's not practical to make the user wait +3000 seconds = 50min. After the upgrade to send the messages later in time in a background process, I plan to do the sleep(1.3)...

Comment: Calling a shell scripts which calls PHP which calls the sleep method is hardly perform very vell...